# Going rate for scientific consultancy to federal governmental entity

Tags: biology

What is the going rate for consulting for a federal government entity. I am a scientist with 42 years of experience in the field.

Comment: "Federal" of which country?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about academia directly.

Comment: @Buzz I think we consider government research labs to be on topic (I sure hope so since I now work at one). Even if government labs are not on topic, consulting seems very much on topic.

Comment: @Buzz I agree with StrongBad that this is on topic. I have voted to close as unclear, however, since the questioner has not specified what county.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, permanent government researchers are generally paid off the [General Schedule](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/salaries-wages/2016/general-schedule/). The GS scale has a bunch of grades with GS-14 being roughly equivalent to a tenured professor. The steps of the scale are roughly equivalent to years of experience at the grade. With 42 years of experience, you would have probably topped out at $160,000 a year. There are a few researchers who are part of the [Senior Executive Service](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/senior-executive-service/compensation/) and make a little more.

In my department, we pay our independent contractors slightly more than the corresponding GS salary since contracting benefits are much worse than government benefits. We also make sub awards to universities to collaborate with faculty. We tend to pay whatever their salary and fringe comes out to.